# Restrict Access to a Node Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I would like specific nodes to only be available to authenticated users in drupal 7. Most modules that I have seen are still in development.

Effectively I need to create a few members only pages. Basically any content in this node cannot be accessed is visitor is not logged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go ahead and use the [node access](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module even though it's in dev. The warnings are mostly the author trying to say he doesn't want to be held responsible.

Otherwise you'll need to manually do it by implementing [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in a custom module

Comment: forgot to accept this a while back. did end up using node access so I figured i better give credit where credit is due

Comment: +1 for hook_node_access check this comment for more detail https://api.drupal.org/comment/63512#comment-63512

Answer (score 0):

The [Node Option Premium](http://drupal.org/project/nopremium) module might do what you want.

> This module adds a new node option Premium content along with core publishing options (Published, Promoted to front page, Sticky at top of lists).
>
> When a node is published as premium content, only users with proper privileges may view the full content of the node.
>
> Non-premium users can still access premium nodes but only get the content rendered in teaser context, even when trying to view the full content. An additional message informs them that the content is available to premium users only.